# Only one wire to chandelier

Tags: electrical

We purchased a new chandelier for our kitchen last year and never for around to installing it. Today we opened the box and realized there is only one wire on the light plus one green screw that we assumed is for the ground wire from the box.

We’ve never seen this before and all of the lights we’ve previously installed had at least 2-3 wires. We’re not master electricians but something seems amiss.

Id love to install it but I’m worried it might be unsafe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5xhf.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5xhf.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn54x.jpg)[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the light ?

Comment: There should be a bundle of wires that you weave through the chain up to the ceiling.

Comment: Sure! I just added more pictures thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the chains to the light and to the mounting plate. Then weave the three wires through the chain up into the mounting plate. Connect the ground wire from the light to the ground from the mounting plate to the ground from the ceiling. Then connect black to black and white to white.